# Firebase multiple where filters with inequality operators

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter using where queries with multiple inequality operators but got ERROR FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'response_date' and 'request_date' how to solve it?

```
getRequest(id, data) {
    console.log(data);
    return this.firestore
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(id)
      .collection('requests', (x) => {
        let result: Query<DocumentData> = x;
        if (data.fileSize)
          result = result
            .where('file_size', '>=', +data.fileSize)
            .where('file_size', '<', +data.fileSize + 0.001);

        //Response Date
        let date: Date | null = null;
        if (data.responseDate) {
          date = new Date(data.responseDate);
          console.log(date);
          var day = date?.getDate();
          var month = date?.getMonth();
          month! += 1;
          var year = date?.getFullYear();
          var fullDate =
            (day?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + day : day) +
            '.' +
            (month?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + month : month) +
            '.' +
            year;
          day! += 1;
          var endDate =
            (day?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + day : day) +
            '.' +
            (month?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + month : month) +
            '.' +
            year;

          result = result
            .where('response_date', '>=', fullDate)
            .where('response_date', '<', endDate);
        }
        //Request Date
        let dateNow: Date | null = null;
        if (data.requestDate) {
          dateNow = new Date(data.requestDate);
          console.log(dateNow);
          var day = dateNow?.getDate();
          var month = dateNow?.getMonth();
          month! += 1;
          var year = dateNow?.getFullYear();
          var fullDate =
            (day?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + day : day) +
            '.' +
            (month?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + month : month) +
            '.' +
            year;
          day! += 1;
          var endDate =
            (day?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + day : day) +
            '.' +
            (month?.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + month : month) +
            '.' +
            year;

          result = result
            .where('request_date', '>=', fullDate)
            .where('request_date', '<', endDate);
        }
        if (data.traceID) result = result.where('trace_id', '==', data.traceID);
        if (data.status) result = result.where('status', '==', +data.status);

        return result;
      })
      .snapshotChanges();   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same a while back to get and filter a date var

```
.where('dateNow', '<', taskDate)
.where('availableDate', '>', taskDate)
.get()
```

create query on firebase and use querybuilder to test it to make sure it works, that worked fine for me I had multiple filters and the backend is running just fine, create the query on firebase with a test case that will return desired results so you have a test case